# How to import MDB file, read and save in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

I need to import .MDB file, read and save in SQL Server. 
I tried this:

### **Method Import**

```
protected void Btn_Importar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/msaccess")
            {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + filename);
                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully!";
                    //ReadMdb();
                    Insert();
            }
    }
}
```

### **Method Insert**

```
public void Insert()
{
        string strFile = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/teste.mdb");
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strFile;
        var myDataTable = new DataTable();
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + strFile))
        {
            connection.Open();
                var query = "SELECT * FROM BOLETO";
                var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                Conexaocs con = new Conexaocs();
                con.Conexao();

                SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BOLETO (CODIGO,NF_CONTA,TEXTO) VALUES (@CODIGO, @NF_CONTA, @TEXTO)", conn);

                //if (reader.HasRows)
                //{
                //    while (reader.Read())
                //    {
                //        //ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + " - " + reader.GetString(1));
                //    }

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO", reader[i]);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NF_CONTA", reader[i]);
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEXTO", reader[i]);
                        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                connection.Close();
        }
}
```

---

But, when come this point not save!

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
   sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO", reader[i]);
   sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NF_CONTA", reader[i]);
   sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEXTO", reader[i]);
   sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

**Message error:** *System.InvalidOperationException: There are no data for the row or column*
[image]

Some idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gord Thompson say you need to iterate through the rows, not the fields. Try the following (untested) code:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO", reader[0]);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NF_CONTA", reader[1]);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEXTO", reader[2]);
        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Não existem dados para a linha ou coluna

apparently means

> There are no data for the row or column

You opened the `OleDbDataReader` but you didn't `Read()` from it. (You did once upon a time, but that `while` loop has been commented out.)